# Convert JSON Key or JWK into Java HashMap<String,Object>

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm currently reading in JWK token from a parameter store into a Java properties file. Once it's in the property file I read it form there and get something in this format back.

```
"{ private: { a: adasdas, b: asdasdasd, c: asdasdas} }"
```

Is there a way to turn this into a `hashMap<string, object>` so that I can grab the private object?

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid json, so ObjectMapper won't be able to parse it.

As a workaround, you could use the following code to preprocess the json string and then parse it:

```
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String invalidJson ="{ private: { a: adasdas, b: asdasdasd, c: asdasdas} }";
            invalidJson = (invalidJson .replaceAll(":\"?([^{|^]*?)\"?(?=[,|}|\\]])",":\"$1\"").replaceAll("\"?(\\w+)\"?(?=:)","\"$1\""));
            Map<String, Object> theMap = objectMapper.readValue(invalidJson , Map.class);
            System.out.println(theMap.get("private"))
```